# Iterate with binary structure over numpy array to get cell sums

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy, scipy

In the package scipy there is the function to define a binary structure (such as a taxicab (2,1) or a chessboard (2,2)).

```
import numpy
from scipy import ndimage
a = numpy.zeros((6,6), dtype=numpy.int) 
a[1:5, 1:5] = 1;a[3,3] = 0 ; a[2,2] = 2
s = ndimage.generate_binary_structure(2,2) # Binary structure
#.... Calculate Sum of 
result_array = numpy.zeros_like(a)
```

What i want is to iterate over all cells of this array with the given structure s. Then i want to append a function to the current cell value indexed in a empty array (example function sum), which uses the values of all cells in the binary structure.

For example:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

# The array a. The value in cell 1,2 is currently one. Given the structure s and an example function such as sum the value in the resulting array (result_array) becomes 7 (or 6 if the current cell value is excluded).

Someone got an idea?

Comment: where did you get ndimage from?

Comment: ohh, sorry. You have to import it from scipy. Edited the post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the particular case of sums, you could use [ndimage.convolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html):

```
In [42]: import numpy as np

In [43]: a = np.zeros((6,6), dtype=np.int) 
a[1:5, 1:5] = 1;
a[3,3] = 0;
a[2,2] = 2

In [48]: s = ndimage.generate_binary_structure(2,2) # Binary structure

In [49]: ndimage.convolve(a,s)
Out[49]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1],
       [2, 5, 7, 7, 4, 2],
       [3, 7, 9, 9, 5, 3],
       [3, 7, 9, 9, 5, 3],
       [2, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]])
```

For the particular case of products, you could use the fact that `log(a*b) = log(a)+log(b)` to convert the problem back to one involving sums. For example, if we wanted to "product-convolve" `b`:

```
b = a[1:-1, 1:-1]
print(b)
# [[1 1 1 1]
#  [1 2 1 1]
#  [1 1 0 1]
#  [1 1 1 1]]
```

we could compute:

```
print(np.exp(ndimage.convolve(np.log(b), s, mode = 'constant')))
# [[ 2.  2.  2.  1.]
#  [ 2.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 2.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 1.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

The situation becomes more complicated if `b` includes negative values:

```
b[0,1] = -1
print(b)
# [[ 1 -1  1  1]
#  [ 1  2  1  1]
#  [ 1  1  0  1]
#  [ 1  1  1  1]]
```

but not impossible:

```
logb = np.log(b.astype('complex'))
real, imag = logb.real, logb.imag
print(np.real_if_close(
    np.exp(
        sum(j * ndimage.convolve(x, s, mode = 'constant')
            for x,j in zip((real, imag),(1,1j))))))
# [[-2. -2. -2.  1.]
#  [-2. -0. -0.  0.]
#  [ 2.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 1.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: thanks for providing some examples. However the function sum is just an example. I want to apply various functions to the cell vicinity values (even custom made ones). How does convolve work? Does it apply the function x to each cell value? I need something which returns all values for the cells vicinity to work on (so for cell 1,2 it should work on [0,1,1,2,1,1,0,0,1]

Comment: Think of `s` as defining a patch or a mask indicating which cells to add together. So for each cell in `a`, the patch is placed over that cell, the neighboring cells are selected, and summed. `convolve` returns an array composed of those summed values. You can also apply different weights to the cells using the `weight` parameter. But `convolve` is always going to perform a sum. I do not know of any `scipy` function which allows you to perform a calculation like `convolve` except with an arbitrary function.

Comment: However, the example above tries to show how you might extend the possibilities by applying ufuncs before or after `convolve`.

Comment: mhh, okay. I will work with that and report back in case i've found no solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's easier if you use a 2-deep wall of zeroes:

```
In [11]: a0
Out[11]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [12]: b0 = zeros_like(a0)

In [13]: for i in range(1,len(a0)-1):
   ....:     for j in range(1,len(a0)-1):
   ....:         b0[i,j] = sum(a0[i-1:i+2, j-1:j+2] * s)
```

This enables you to multiply the two sub-matrices together and sum, as desired. (You could also do something more elaborate here...)

```
In [14]: b0
Out[14]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  5.,  7.,  7.,  4.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  7.,  9.,  9.,  5.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  7.,  9.,  9.,  5.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  4.,  5.,  5.,  3.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [15]: b0[1:len(b0)-1, 1:len(b0)-1]
Out[15]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  5.,  7.,  7.,  4.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  7.,  9.,  9.,  5.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  7.,  9.,  9.,  5.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  4.,  5.,  5.,  3.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  1.]])
```

Comment: The function sum is just an example. I want to apply various functions to the cells vicinity values (even custom made ones). Additionally your script could be a little bit slow (two loops) when confronted with large arrays. Nevertheless +1